# DPI resolution of Epson MX-80 vs IBM graphics printer 5152 different in quadruple density mode?

Tags: graphics, printer

I have been trying to figure out why the IBM graphics printer has a higher dpi in quadruple density , than the Epson MX-80 since technically the IBM graphics printer is a rebranded version of the MX-80.

Both printers have the same dpi resolution for single density and double density graphics mode, but when it gets to quadruple density the dpi is different vertically. The MX-80 in quadruple density mode has a resolution of 240 x 144 dpi , while the IBM graphics printer is 240 x 216 dpi.

I am guessing if the IBM graphics printer can do 240 x 216 dpi , so probably can the MX-80. Maybe there isn't a difference in print quality when printing with those resolutions? I know the print head is 72 dpi vertically, and has to overlap the dots to get 144 dpi, to get 216 dpi I am guessing the dots have to overlap even more?

Someone on here probably knows a correct answer to why the quadruple density is different on these printers even if they are technically the same printer.

Comment: I'm a bit confused - the Epson MX printer manual (e.g. at bitsavers, http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/epson/printer/MX_Printer_Manual_1982.pdf) quite clearly talks about "one-third dot vertical spacing" and setting line spacings in units of 216'ths of an inch.

Comment: So it was possible to do that, but that option may not have been implemented by specific printer drivers.

Comment: The Star Gemini 10x printer was mostly Epson-compatible, but used 1/144" vertical spacing.  I don't recall any other Epson-style printers doing likewise.  The Apple ImageWriter did, but I recall it was different in other ways.

Comment: @JonCuster The driver included with windows , for the Epson MX-80 only has 240 x 144 as a option , even though the windows driver for the IBM graphics printer does have it as 240 x 216.

Comment: Interesting - so it would seem that it is a driver issue. Why Epson decided to hobble their driver is odd (unless IBM still had enough clout to impact it?).

Comment: @JonCuster Even all other Epson 9-pin dot matrix printers newer than the MX-80,  including Epson's modern 9-pin printers,  have it as a max of 240 x 144 to this day, and checking various printers including modern 9-pin printers , still have it listed as supporting 216 line spacing per inch.  There are other 9-pin printers that are not Epson that list the max dpi as 240 x 144,  The only other 9-pin printers I have seen that support 240 x 216 are Okidata printers.

Comment: Signum! on Atari ST was one of the first programs to print in full 1/240 x 1/216 resolution. I remember my PC and Mac colleagues jealous on the paper I could print on my small Seikosha printer that they could not on their so expensive machines.

Comment: @JonCuster that makes sense, since 216 = 72x3.

Comment: The superscript/subscript functions on the Epson is designed to print all the even dots of a font consecutively, advance the paper by a fraction of a dot, and then print the odd dots, a design which behaves as though the "fraction of a dot" were 1/144", even though it isn't quite (which leads to superscript/subscript text being a little wonky looking).

Comment: The question is poorly worded. "single density", "double density", "quadruple density" only affects the *horizontal* dpi, and that one is 240 dpi on all of those printers. Also, the vertical resolution of those printers during the execution of any graphics mode command is 72dpi. The actual question is about the paper motion, especially the availablility of a 1/3-pin step, which is not directly related to any graphics command. To print in 240x144 or 240x216, the printer driver needs to handle the paper motion and line interleaving in software.

Comment: @MichaelKarcher obviously people should know what I mean, that the vertical resolution in the printer drivers for the MX-80 and IBM graphics printer , is the same for single density and double density. But when when you get to the quadruple density ( 240 dpi horizontal ) , the vertical dpi is different in the printer driver settings for each model.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at page 43 (PDF page 49) of the [original MX-80 manual](https://minuszerodegrees.net/manuals/Epson/Epson%20MX-80%20FT%20-%20Operation%20Manual.pdf) under the ESC G command, it achieves bold characters by double printing with a 1/216 inch paper advance.  So obviously the paper feed mechanism was capable of 216 positions per inch, but it seems the ability to use this capability was extremely limited.

The Graftrax extension added the ESC 3 command to set line spacing in 1/216 inch increments.  It may have also exposed other ways to use the 1/216 capabilities but I can't find a good reference at the moment.

Comment: The other limitation of most MX-80 ESC-3 compatible 9 pin printers were that they could not fire the pins on 2 successive pixel columns. In practice this meant that only a 1/120th inch horizontal resolution. The first program I know that enabled true 1/240 x 1/216 was the German text system Signum! on the Atari ST. Printing in this maximal resolution was extremely long as it made 2x3 passes for 9 pixel rows (1 hour printing a LQ A4 on my Seikosha SP-80 f.ex.).

Comment: Nearly all of the Epson-compatible printers I've seen have two speeds of horizontal motion, can address 120dpi at faster speed and 240dpi at slower speed, and are limited to striking dots in every other position.  Some Panasonic models add a third speed for carriage motion without printing.

Comment: @MarkRansom Not sure if anyone else has caught this yet, but your link for the original mx-80 manual goes to the wrong link? I would have edited it to fix it, if I would have known where a link to the original manual is online.

Comment: @MichaelWeaser it worked for me when I posted it, and it just worked again.  It's a very long PDF though, so maybe it just didn't finish loading for you.

Comment: @MarkRansom Thats odd , for me the link goes to an microsoft office manual?

Comment: @MichaelWeaser I apologize, that link is one I was using to answer a completely different question.  I don't know how it got here.  I'll try to fix it, but probably not until tonight.

Comment: https://archive.org/details/Seikosha_SP-180AI_Matrix_Printer_Owners_Manual/page/n75/mode/2up shows the command for an EPSON/IBM compatible printer to switch between 1/144 and 1/216 line spacing.

Comment: @MichaelWeaser I'm so sorry about that, the link is fixed now.